# How to show product category in admin grid

Tags: magento2

I have a grid in admin where I am showing orders based on some filters,

I want to show the  category of ordered item in one of the column ,How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by joining grid collection  with  table ,

```
catalog_category_entity_varchar`

$categoryNameTable=$collection->getTable('catalog_category_entity_varchar');

 $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('category_name'=>$categoryNameTable),
            '`category_product`.category_id = category_name.row_id AND category_name.attribute_id=45',
            ['catalog' => 'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_name.value)']);
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Magento option to do this, however you can create a product attribute Ex "category_grid", assigne products to that attribute and add it in the product grid view.